# Connecting Hand and Wrist

Tags: modeling

Having a problem with connecting hand to wrist/arm. I've tried a few different methods, and so I've found the best one that looks the best, but there's still a clear divide where the two are connected. Looked for interior faces, doubled points, etc., but nothing of that sort. Is there an easy fix for this?
[image: Object mode, with subdivision modifier]

[image: Wireframe mode, with section in question highlighted]

Comment: please show an image of your mesh in wireframe view.

Comment: Looks like either a case of inconsistent normals, or an internal face. There may also be different materials attached to each part of the mesh

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Normals are fine, as far as I can tell. Tried a fix for normals and it didn't change anything. There are no internal faces. Additionally there are no materials attached to the item

Comment: @cegaton edited

Comment: @Jude did you remove doubles?

Comment: @cegaton I wish it was that easy, but yes I did remove doubles :/

Comment: @Jude Can you upload the file?

Comment: I would check normals in Edit Mode > Properties (N) > Mesh Display > Normals > Face Normals and then make sure the lines are all pointing outwards from the model

Comment: @Xuan Yep all face normals are facing the correct direction.

Comment: Switch to face select mode and remove the internal face in that area.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by deleting the apparently corrupted points, re-extruding from the arm and then reconnecting the points. Dunno why or how the method I was using before was being troublesome. Thanks to all the help.